# TypeError in calculations with user-input values

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I realize this has been answered but Im a super noob. I know it has to do with male/female being a string but I thought I had it defined? How can I get the calculation to work?

```
num = int(input('Please enter number of standard drinks consumed:'))
while num <= 0:
    print ('Error: The number cannot be negative or zero.')
    num = int(input('Please enter number of standard drinks consumed:'))
weight = int(input('Please enter weight in pounds:'))
while weight <= 0:
    print ('Error: The weight cannot be negative or zero.')
    weight = int(input('Please enter weight in pounds:'))
time = int(input('Please enter number of hours since first drink:'))
while time <= 0:
    print ('Error: The time cannot be negative or zero.')
    time = int(input('Please enter number of hours since first drink:'))
gender = input('Please enter the sex male or female:')
male = 0.68
female = 0.55


B = -0.015 * time(2.84 * num / weight * gender)
print ('The BAC is', format(B, ',.2f'))
```

Comment: you haven't defined anything - that the `gender` variable can take a value that happens to be the same with the name of another variable doesn't mean anything, `gender`,`male` and `female` are totally different variables...

Comment: `gender` stores some text input, and then you try to multiply a number with that text later. This will obviously not work. Make `gender` to be a number, you have an example of doing that in your code snippet.

Comment: Thank you I feel like that should have been way more obvious Ive only worked with python for a month but still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget, in Python indentation is used to define a block of code. If not indented, the lines following `while` are executed only once. Secondly, you will need to convert the `gender` variable into the correct numerical value (depending on the user input) before calculating the BAC. Finally, I believe you want to change the calculation so that you are actually *multiplying* with the`time` variable.

Here's an example that demonstrates how to fix these problems. Notice that this script allows a few different options for the user input, and converts everything to lower-case before checking `gender`:

```
gender = input('Please enter the sex male or female:').lower()
while gender not in ['m', 'f', 'male', 'female']:
    print ("Error: Gender must be male or female.")
    gender = input('Please enter the sex male or female:').lower()

if gender in ['male', 'm']:
    gender = 0.68
else:
    gender = 0.55

B = -0.015 * time * 2.84 * num / weight * gender
print ('The BAC is {0:.6f}'.format(B))
```

I also took the liberty of changing the formatted output a bit. Note, with Python 2.x you need to replace `input` with `raw_input` to automatically get the `gender` value as a string.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm using python 3 because when I go to run the finished code it always goes with .55...I cannot seem to get it to select male.

Comment: @JonathanPeriman It shouldn't matter. I suspect you haven't indented the line: `gender=0.55`. If it isn't indented, the `gender` set in the `if-else` structure is not used. BTW, I wonder if you have the correct equation, or the right values set for each gender? By this calculation, the BAC is always greater for males for a given time/num/weight ... I thought it worked the other way around.

Comment: Thats the equation given to me and the coefficients assigned by the teacher. So even if theyre wrong its his problem lol. Ill double check everything and maybe ask about that it did seem strange. I check myself against my 110 lb gf and hers was lower....

Comment: ugh man thank you so much I had indented the if. And the formula is old but correct and so is male and female. Thats all i needed to fix to have this puppy finished. It was supposed to take less than a day.

Answer (score 0):

there are several mistakes in your code. First of all, try to uphold proper indentation. For example, `while` loop should look like that:

```
weight = int(input('Please enter weight in pounds:'))
while weight <= 0:
    print ('Error: The weight cannot be negative or zero.')
    weight = int(input('Please enter weight in pounds:'))

time = int(input('Please enter number of hours since first drink:'))
while time <= 0:
    print ('Error: The time cannot be negative or zero.')
    time = int(input('Please enter number of hours since first drink:'))
```

On your male or female coefficient. You haven't defined them. You just create variables `male` and `female` and set them to some values. What you want to do is:

```
gender = input('Please enter the sex male or female:')
gender_coeficients = {male: 0.68, female: 0.55}
B = -0.015 * time(2.84 * num / weight * gender_coeficients[gender])
```

Like that you created a dictionary with two keys, each corresponding to one gender, and paired them with coefficients' values. Those can be used by `dictionary[key]` statement (`gender_coeficients[gender]` in your case).
It would be also beneficial to create `if-else` statement to check if a user really typed in male or female.

If you are interested how should a proper python code look like, check:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
But most importantly, have fun coding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ive got way more to learn about python.

Comment: Also I do have the code properly indented in python but messed with it when I posted the question.

Comment: @JonathanPeriman oh, in that case I am sorry for pointing that out :-)